# How to Get Support Annotations in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, annotations

I want to use support annotations in Eclipse. So that i can import these statements in Eclipse.

```
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

You can read it about here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations

Pls don't Suggest to use Android Studio!

Answer (score 0):

You can import android-support-v4.jar for these annotations

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain how this works? How do you import support for these? What buttons do you click?